# pay seperate paypal accounts a percentage of the sale

Tags: paypal, split, account

I want to set up a button on one of my sites where I sell a product for $100 I want the transaction to split the $100 automatically, $80 to the suppliers PayPal account and $20 to my PayPal account.
How can this be achieved

Answer (score 0):

You would do this via [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) via parallel payments. You can apply for it on developer.paypal.com